# When are suspend card counterable

Tags: magic-the-gathering

When can you counter a suspend card (when it is suspended or when the final time counters get removed) and would I need to play a counterspell (counter a spell) or a stifle (counters an ability) to do so?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

When you move a suspend card from your hand to the exile zone, you are performing a special action, much like playing a land. This cannot be stopped by a [Counterspell](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Counterspell), nor even by a card like [Stifle](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Stifle).

Each of your subsequent upkeeps, a triggered ability removes a time counter. This can be stopped by a card like [Stifle](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Stifle). (Note: Stifling the "remove a counter" trigger won't permanently stop the spell, you will simply delay the spell by a turn.)

When the final time counter is removed, another triggered ability (which can also be the target of [Stifle](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Stifle) and friends) will cast the suspended spell upon resolution. At that point, the spell will finally be on the stack, and a legal target for cards such as [Counterspell](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Counterspell).

Comment: Only thing I would add is that Stifling the "remove a counter" trigger doesn't permanently stop the spell; it just delays it by a turn. If you actually want to stop the spell altogether, you'll want to wait for the last counter to come off.

Answer (score 3):

Suspended cards have three abilities, two of which may be countered. To understand why, we first need to understand how to counter a spell, and the various abilities associated with the `Suspend` keyword.

> 701.5a To counter a spell or ability means to cancel it, removing it from the stack.

Now we know that a spell or ability must be on the stack in order to be countered. Now we explore the three Suspend abilities, and determine which can be countered and which can't.

**First Ability**

> Suspend N—[cost]” means “If you could begin to cast this card by putting it onto the stack from your hand, you may pay [cost]
> and exile it with N time counters on it. This action does not use the
> stack

The first ability is a *special action* that does not use the stack. It cannot be countered or even responded to at all.

**Second Ability**

> At the beginning of your upkeep, if this card is suspended, remove a
> time counter from it

The second ability is a *triggered ability* that uses the stack. It can be countered by [Stifle](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Stifle). This typically only serves to delay the suspension by a single turn.

**Third Ability**

> When the last time counter is removed from this card, if it’s exiled,
> play it without paying its mana cost if able. If you can’t, it remains
> exiled. If you cast a creature spell this way, it gains haste until
> you lose control of the spell or the permanent it becomes.

This final ability is also a *triggered ability* which puts a *spell* on the stack. The triggered ability may be countered with [Stifle](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Stifle), or the spell may be countered by [Counterspell](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Counterspell). If the ability is countered, the previously suspended card remains in exile, where it is typically never able to trigger again. Countered spells go to the graveyard.

Comment: WRT third ability: The ability doesn't "end up as a spell on the stack," but rather the _resolution of the ability_ puts a spell on the stack (and moves a card from the exile zone to the stack zone). If the trigger is countered with Stifle, the suspend card itself stays in exile forever (barring Pull from Eternity/Riftsweeper style shenanigans) without ever having seen the stack or been a spell.

Comment: @BrianS Corrected.